# How can I add an image to a <li> tag dynamically

Tags: html, css, html-lists, background-image

I want to add an image that is placed below each li menu item like a menu seperator. How to I go about doing this in the CSS. I want the images to dynamically render when I add another li tag to the ul.

HTML code:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>Bookmarks</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>BUMPER STICKERS</li>
    <li>CARBONLESS FORMS</li>
    <li>CD JACKETS</li>
    <li>DIE CUT/CUSTOM STICKERS</li>
    <li>DOOR HANGERS</li>
    <li>ENVELOPES</li>
    <li>FOLDERS</li>
    <li>LETTERHEADS</li>
    <li>RECTANGULAR STICKERS</li>
    <li>ROUND STICKERS</li>
    <li>STATIC CLING</li>
    <li>TABLE TENTS</li>
    <li>VINYL BANNERS</li>
    <li>WINDOW STICKERS</li>
</ul>
```

Css:

```
.seperator li {
    background-image: url(../Images/Template%20Images/Seperator.png);
    padding: 1px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 890px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: run-in;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with this code?

Comment: ^ you gotta tell us what you are trying to do. lol

Comment: Im trying to add a background image under each `<ul>` with just one css class so that I can dynamically add the image to every `<li>` tag

Comment: to add images dynamically to the `<li>` see this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Nkn5w/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the li have a background image that is positioned to be far enough from the top that the text will not overlap it. Here is a how you position a background image:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

Just adjust the element height to include x pixels for the text line plus the height of the background image.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. Of course you will have to tweak it to your needs and requirements.

```
.menu li{
    background: url(line.jpg) bottom left no-repeat;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

<ul class="menu">
    <li>Bookmarks</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>BUMPER STICKERS</li>
    <li>CARBONLESS FORMS</li>
    <li>CD JACKETS</li>
    <li>DIE CUT/CUSTOM STICKERS</li>
    <li>DOOR HANGERS</li>
    <li>ENVELOPES</li>
    <li>FOLDERS</li>
    <li>LETTERHEADS</li>
    <li>RECTANGULAR STICKERS</li>
    <li>ROUND STICKERS</li>
    <li>STATIC CLING</li>
    <li>TABLE TENTS</li>
    <li>VINYL BANNERS</li>
    <li>WINDOW STICKERS</li>
</ul>
```